# Core data requests does not work on background thread when in app in background mode in Xcode

Tags: xcode, core-data, background-fetch

I execute core data request *not* on main thread when my app is called to do background fetch (app state is background), and method freezes forever.
But when I use main thread, it works.

Should I always use main thread for core data when in background mode? Does there is some apple doc about it?

Comment: There is no such restriction.  Unfortunately, your question lacks any useful information for anyone to provide assistance.

Comment: Thanks. Which info should I provide? I create private queue - based context, set main context as its parent, and execute fetchRequest. It works when app is active or inactive, but not when app is background

Comment: Code of how you handle running in the background, and code for what you do while running in the background.

Comment: Are you *always* using either `performBlock` or `performBlockAndWait` when accessing Core Data?

Comment: @TomHarrington yes, so my code runs in correct thread (the one used by context)